# How to make a cylinder smooth without smooth shading?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I want to 3d print a .stl file of a cube with a cylinder coming from it, but blender's default cylinder isn't smooth, and smooth shading is just an optical illusion. I don't know if I should just use the sub surface modifier a lot, or something else?

Comment: Hello :). If you need more edges, simply increase them to a higher number, when adding the cylinder. Default 16 is rather low.

Comment: I want it to (hopefully) be perfectly smooth, like how it LOOKS in smooth shading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot technically do this in blender. However, you can increase the number of faces to the point where the printer’s resolution dot is bigger than the width of the faces. I think this is impractical however, and recommend you print it out a little rough, then do some sanding work.

Comment: I'll try it, one last question though, if you turn on smooth shading and then put the file in something like unity or unreal engine, will it still be smooth since it technically doesn't change the model?

Comment: I don’t know. It probably should, though, if Unity uses normals for its OpenGL rendering at all.

Comment: To be safe, I might use custom split normals data instead of “auto smooth,” or even use and apply the “edge split” modifier if that doesn’t work.

Comment: Simply adding a lot of verticies looks great!